# replace multiple strings in python

Tags: python, text, replace

I would like to replace certain strings which are not hard coded as per my requirement like inputFile,outputFile and outputFileSize
eg

```
COMMAND = """Application.exe inputFile=./Input.txt 
outputFile="Output/Output.txt" outputFileSize=20Kb"""
```

I would like to do

> inputfilename = './File1.txt'
>
> outputfilename = 'Output/File2.txt'
>
> outputfilesize = '90Kb'

So that my replaced string should look like this

```
COMMAND = """Application.exe inputFile=./File1.txt 
outputFile="Output/File2.txt" outputFileSize=90Kb"""
```

what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What about `COMMAND = """Application.exe inputFile={},  outputFile="{}" outputFileSize={}""".format(inputfilename, outputfilename, outputfilesize)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```py
command = """Application.exe inputFile=./Input.txt 
outputFile="Output/Output.txt" outputFileSize=20Kb"""

inputfilename = './File1.txt'
outputfilename = 'Output/File2.txt'
outputfilesize = '90Kb'

command = command.replace("./Input.txt", inputfilename)
command = command.replace("Output/Output.txt", outputfilename)
command = command.replace("20Kb", outputfilesize)

print command
```

Output:

```
Application.exe inputFile=./File1.txt 
outputFile="Output/File2.txt" outputFileSize=90Kb
```

Hints:

- Your input string contains a line break. So it might cause trouble when executing the command.
- You might want to introduce dedicated placeholders like "INPUT", "OUTPUT" and so on. But using "./Input.txt" works as well.
- For more information about the `string.replace` method, have a look into [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).
- As commented by jojo, the approach can be shortened significantly. But I don't know the exact scenario (e.g. why you want to replace the arguments instead of constructing the correct command in the first place).

Comment: thanks i didn't know that it was so easy to do. I was confused with the solution i have searched in google

Comment: @user1891916: you should use string formatting instead (as [@jojo's suggested)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760150/replace-multiple-strings-in-python#comment51453057_31760150)